# DISCORD.JS how to dm a @user for verfication

Tags: discord.js

```
client.on('message', msg => {
    if(msg.content.startsWith('^approvedpr'))
    (What do I put here)? 
});
```

I tried all the code from other people and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can send a DM to another user with `msg.author.send` check out the [message class
documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) for everything you can do.

```
client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.content.startsWith('^approvedpr') {
        msg.author.send("Whatever");
    };
};
```

EDIT: If you're trying to DM a mentioned user, you can use `msg.mentions.users` ([documentation link](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=mentions))

```
client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.content.startsWith('^approvedpr') {
        //Get the first user that was mentioned
        const mention = msg.mentions.users.first();

        //Send them a DM
        mention.send("Whatever");
    };
};
```